# Is $\{(a,5a)\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G=\mathbb {R}\times \mathbb {R}$ be the group under binary operation $*$ defined by $(a, b)*(c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$. Let $H = \{(a, 5a) \mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}.$ Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Describe the left cosets of $H$ in $G$. Describe this subgroup and its cosets geometrically.

My solution goes like this:

> Given $H = \{(a, 5a) \mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Now if $(a, 5a),(b, 5b)$ then, $(a, 5a)*(b, 5b)=(a+b, 5(a+b))\in H.$ If $(a, 5a)\in H$, then $(-a, -5a)\in H$. Hence $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. If $(a_1,b_1) \in G$, then the left coset of $H$ in $G$ is $(a_1,b_1)*H=\{(a_1,b_1)*(a,5a)=(a_1+a, b_1+5a),a\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{(a_1+a, b_1+5a),a\in\mathbb{R}\}.$ The subgroup $H=\{(a,5a)\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$, if $y=5a$ and $x=a$, then $y=5x$ and hence the subgroup $H$ represents a straight line. The left coset of $H$ in $G$, $(a_1,b_1)*H=\{(a_1+a, b_1+5a)\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\},$  if $y=b_1+5a$  and $x=a_1+a$, then $y= x + (b_1-a_1+4a)$ and hence, it represents a straight line.

Is the above solution correct? Is it valid? If not, then where is it going wrong? I am not quite getting it.

Comment: Any $(a,b) \in G$ could be written as $(a,5a)+(0,b-5a)$ (of course, $*$ should be denoted $+$ instead).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thank you! But is the solution correct?...

Comment: To prove that a subset $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup, the first thing u need to verify is that it is not empty, usually this is done by proving that the identity of G belongs to H regarding the inverse, jut a small remark, it is better to write it (-a,5(-a)).  Geometrically, H is the line passing through the origin having the equation $y=5x$,and the cosets are lines  parallel  to H.

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane Thank you! Actually I used two axioms used for proving $H$ as a subgroup  1.if $a,b\in H$ , then $a.b\in H$ 2.If $a\in H$ , then $a^{-1}\in H$...

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane Thanks a lot! But how to prove that the  left cosets of $H$ in $G$ are straight lines parallel to $H$ ? I am not quite getting it...$H$ is non empty as $e=(0,0)\in H$(where the identity element of $G$ is denoted by $e$)...

Comment: Are all the instances of $R$ supposed to be $\mathbb{R}$? If not, what is $R$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes! Its $\mathbb {R}$... I have edited it...

Comment: Subject line still messed up. Changed it for you, as it was not a good subject line anyway.

Comment: Subject line is not a place for **detail**. That's what the post is for. The subject line is supposed to be a succint and informative statement about the general content of the post.

Comment: You know I wish there was some way to select text and mathjax combo and cut and paste *as* text and mathjax combo.  You answer is correct but could be "stylistically" improved. You say "if (a,5a), (b,5b) then"... If (a,5a),(b,5b) *what*? ... I think you meant "if $(a,5a),(b,5b)\in H$... and other little glitches.  I personally would like it if you specify what relevance $(a+b,5(a+b))\in H$ has (It shows the operation is closed) and why $(-a,-5a)\in H$ is enough to conclude it is a group....(basically either go into more detail or less)... but yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

As @belkacem abderrahmane told you, you forgot to verify $(0,0)=(0,5\times 0)\in \color{red}H$.

By the way, you made a mistake at the end : "$... y=b_1+5a$ and $x=a_1+5a$, then $y= \color{red}5x+b_1-5a_1...$"[if you want a straight line equation $y=\alpha x+\beta(\alpha,\beta \in \Bbb R)$, you can't use $a$ which depends on $x$].

$\color{red}H$ is a line of $\Bbb R^2$ passing through $(0,0)$. Let $(a_1,b_1)\in \Bbb R^2$ and $t:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2, (x,y)\mapsto (a_1+x,b_1+y)=(a_1,b_1)*(x,y)$. $t$ is the translation of vector $(a_1,b_1).$ And a coset of $\color{red}H$ in $G$ is $\{t((x,y)):(x,y)\in \color{red}H\}=t(\color{red}H)$; a coset of $\color{red}H$ in $G$ is then the image of $\color{red}H$ by the translation of vector $(a_1,b_1)$, i.e. a line $\color{red}{\text{parallel}}$ to $H$.

This is why the first line has the equation $y=5x$ and the second $y=\color{red}5x+\beta$[the lines are parallel since they are images of each other by a translation , they have the same slope.]

I remind you that the cosets are equivalence classes and form a partition of $\Bbb R^2$, here a partition formed of parallel lines with slope 5.
[image]

Comment: I take it that has been demonstrated that to prove a subset $H$ with inherited operation of a group, that to prove it is a subgroup it is sufficient to show that $e\in H$.  That the operation is closed on the subset, and that for every element in $H$ the inverse is in as well.  But it's always nice to cite that.

Comment: @Franklin: I made additions to my answer to try to better answer your questions. Don't hesitate to ask me other questions if any gray areas remain.

Answer (score 0):

Given two vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then the line from $x$ to $y$ can be written $f(t)=x + t(y-x)$ and we can see that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. This line will be parallel to $t(y-x)$ which goes through the origin because $x + t(y-x)-(t(y-x))=x$ which is constant with respect to $t$.

In this problem we have $H=a(1,5)$ This is to say we have $u-w = a(1,5)$ for some fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Now a simple rearrangement shows $w=u+a(1,5)$ so $u$ and $w$ are in the same coset if and only if they are on the same line which is parallel to $a(1,5)$.

Comment: Thank you! However,  in my solution the subgroup $H$ represents $y=5x$ and the left coset is represented as $y=x+(b_1-a_1+4a)$...so how can we say $y=x+(b_1-a_1+4a)$ parallel to the equation of the subgroup?...

Comment: @Franklin Because that's where you made a mistake. Note that when $a_1=b_1=0$ the slope should be $5$ because $(1,5)$ is a point in the coset through the origin. Firstly, you're expressing the line as a function of a graph in this form, which is the same as eliminating the parameter $a$.  With  $x = a + a_1$ then $a=x-a_1$ so we have $y=b_1 + 5a=b_1 + 5(x-a_1)= 5x+b_1-5a_1$ which has the right slope and $b_1-5a_1$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So which means the problem occured because the parameter $a$ didn't get eliminated ...and this is because $a$ is a parameter and in the equation concerning $x$ and $y$ and constants like $b_1$ and $a_1$ , $x$ and $y$ is already parameter dependent and so if we eliminate the $a$ then we get a pure equation (which is the required one), right?  Although ,just a question , though is it wrong to have parameter $a$ in the equation of the coset(if we have parameter$a$ in the equation , it still remains an equationofa straight line, but though not in exact form as required)?...

Comment: @Franklin it depends on  what form you're expecting. Personally I'm not a fan of the $y=5x+b_1-5a_1$ form because it's the graph of a function and that doesn't generalize to arbitrary vector spaces while the parameterized version does. The problem gave you the line parameterized by $a$ so I'd assume you don't need to eliminate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So which means my solution goes valid too, although the equation of the coset is $y=x+(b_1-a_1+4a)$ and parameterized by $a$ maybe...but still my whole solution in the original post stands correct , right? Thank you!...

Comment: @Franklin the slope of the line you gave is $1$, which is not $5$, so it's definitely wrong. You'll need fix that.

Comment: Yeah...that's where the problem lies...I dont quite get where it goes wrong? ....

Comment: @Franklin you didn't really spell out the calculation so I don't know either. If I had to guess I think you confused an $a$ with an $a_1$. It's the only way to make sense of the $4$.

Comment: Actually,$$ (a_1,b_1)*H=\{(a_1+a,b_1+5a), a\in \mathbb{R}\}$$(, where $(a_1,b_1)\in G$) so, if $x=a_1+a$ and $y=b_1+5a$, then $y-x=b_1-a_1+4a$ and hence that conclusion follows...

Comment: @Franklin note that you didn't eliminate the parameter though. You've got a two variable function there.

Comment: But still $y=x+(b_1-a_1+4a)$ seems valid as we cannot really say the slope is  $1$ as this equation too depends upon $a$ as a parameter, it may be a different form of the equation of the coset...but still it seems valid, right? ...

Comment: @Franklin it's not wrong, but again it makes $y(a,x)$ a two variable function in this form so the graph will be a plane, not a line. There is a subtle difference between lines in a plane parameterized by vectors and lines in the plane that are the graphs of a function. To move between them you have to eliminate the parameter, which is $a$ in this case.